# str_extract_all returns a list but I want a column in a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-science, stringr

I'd like to use `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package to extract digits from strings, and I'd like the output as numerics in a column of an existing dataframe. The problem is that the `str_extract_all` output's a list.

**UPDATE**: My overall goal is to use the extracted digits to filter the columns of another dataframe called `film_main`. `film_main` is where the data in the originally posted dataframe `film` comes from.

So, if a column in `film_main` has the digits 1 and 0 in the column name, then the only permitted entries in that column are 1s, 0s, and NAs. Any other entry in that column should be set to NA. See below pseudocode and `film_main_desired`.

Sorry for not being very clear in my original post, I thought less was more but I ended up not doing a very good job presenting my problem.

```
# Load package
library(stringr)

# Toy dataset
film_main = data.frame("grey..0..yellow..1.."=c(0, 1, 0, NA, 2), "grey..0..brown..1.."=c(3, 0, 0, NA, 2), "grey..0..blue..1...brown..2.."=c(0, 2, 1, 6, 1), "3grey..0..purple..1...brown..2.."=c(0, 1, 2, 3, NA), "3grey..0..purple..1...brown..2..brown..3.."=c(0, 1, 2, 3, NA))


# Extracting digits using stringr::str_extract_all
film = data.frame(var = names(film_main))
film$var2 = str_extract_all(film$var, "[:digit:]+")

# Result for string extraction
class(film$var2)
"list"    

# Desired result for string extraction 
class(film$var2)
"numeric"

# Filtering film_main - PSEUDOCODE 
lapply(film_main, function(x) ifelse(film_main$x %in% SOME_SORT_OF_A_FILTER_FEATURING_PERMITTED_DIGITS, df_main$x, NA))


# OVERALL GOAL 
film_main_desired= data.frame("grey..0..yellow..1.."=c(0, 1, 0, NA, NA), "grey..0..brown..1.."=c(NA, 0, 0, NA, NA), "grey..0..blue..1...brown..2.."=c(0, 2, 1, NA, 1), "3grey..0..purple..1...brown..2.."=c(0, 1, 2, 3, NA), "3grey..0..purple..1...brown..2..brown..3.."=c(0, 1, 2, 3, NA))
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Each entry will return multiple integers. Do you want multiple columns?

Comment: So how do you want your output? If you want it so that each number matches its color, then my suggestion would be to revisit the source of that data and fix it there. Otherwise, there is no clear pattern

Comment: Please try `film$var2 <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", film$var1)`. Or use `grep("3", film$var1, value = TRUE)` to check for one specific digit.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after? Using a couple of other tidyverse packages - dplyr and tidyr - alongside stringr.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

film2 <- film %>% 
  mutate(var2 = str_extract_all(var1, "[:digit:]+")) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(var2 = as.numeric(var2))
```

Answer (score 0):

if your strings are all next to each other then this is just a bit shorter:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

film2 <- film %>% 
  mutate(var2 = str_extract(var1, "[:digit:]+"),
  var2 = as.numeric(var2))
```